# offset Management for EventHub

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, offset, azure-eventhub

Summary - I am using Scala spark to read eventhub as source and saving as streaming data frame

and my streaming dataframe output looks like below

```
scala> messages.writeStream.outputMode("append").option("truncate", false) .format("console").start() .awaitTermination()
+----------+-----------------------+----------+---+--------+----+-------+
|Offset    |Time (readable)        |Timestamp |id |date    |user|integer|
+----------+-----------------------+----------+---+--------+----+-------+
|4294970696|2022-01-25 07:20:19.082|1643113219|001|01292017|you |2696   |
+----------+-----------------------+----------+---+--------+----+-------+
```

How can I implement offset managent in this code. I understand about the checkpoint location. But I wanted to handle offset management based on my event failure and the next start based on previous offset. I am not able implement this logic. Appreciate some guidance

Comment: You can use [`offsetRanges`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#kafka-itself) to control when/where those offsets get stored

Comment: @OneCricketeer - does this applicable for eventhub? If so does this work on event failures. Thanks for the response, btw